# Php array returning just one of an arrays values when looping through

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array and I am trying to var dump the values so I can see what is being returned but when I use a foreach loop, only one of the values is being dumped even though there are 2 values in the array. Can someone tell me what is incorrect in the code?

PHP

```
$items = ($items['things']);
              
 foreach ($items as $value) {
      var_dump($value);  // Returns just the first thing in my items array i.e. "textbook"
 }
```

If I `var_dump($items)` I get an array like this

```
array:2 [
  0 => "textbook"
  1 => "pencil"
]
```

Comment: I ran your code. It gives my both values as expected. string(8) "textbook" string(6) "pencil"

Comment: @JasonK the var_dump in the foreach loop gave you both items? Hmm

Comment: Each run of the loop gave 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

Its working with me:

```
    $items = [
        'things' => ['a', 'b', 'c']
    ];
    $items = ($items['things']);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        var_dump($item);
    }
```

result:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
```